# How to repeat the LocalNotification only once in a day

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter, localnotification

I create a application in which application notify the users once in a day.

For that I used the following code

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings) {

    scheduleNoticaiftion()
}

// Schedule the Notifications with repeat
func scheduleNoticaiftion() {
    //UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications()

    // Schedule the notification ********************************************

        let notification = UILocalNotification()
        notification.alertBody = "Hey! Upload your latest photos"
        notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
        notification.fireDate = NSDate()
       // notification.category = categoryID
        notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)

}
```

The above code is working fine but the problem is if user opens and close(terminate) the app 6 time in a day.

User get total 6 notification on next day based on application open time i.e. if I open application in 3 p.m and close it and next open application at 4 p.m. it will show the notification in 3pm and 4pm of next day simultaneously.

**Question:**  How can I send only one notification within 24 hours? i.e. If a user install my app at 4pm it will notify the user every day at 4pm ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operating system is responsible for delivering local notifications at their scheduled times.   [see UILocalNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/index.html)
 So operating system  maintain the scheduledLocalNotifications count.

```
func scheduleNotification() {

    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduledLocalNotifications.count == 0 {

        let notification = UILocalNotification()
        notification.alertBody = "Hey! Update your counter ;)"
        notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
        notification.fireDate = NSDate()
        notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
    }
}


func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings) {
    scheduleNotification()
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's because you create new local notification each time user opens the app.

and to repeat the notification once per day use .CalendarUnitDay

try below code

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        if(!NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults() .boolForKey("isNotificationScheduled")){
            scheduleNoticaiftion()
        }
        return true
    }

    // Schedule the Notifications with repeat
    func scheduleNoticaiftion() {
        //UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications()

        // Schedule the notification ********************************************

        let notification = UILocalNotification()
        notification.alertBody = "Hey! Upload your latest photos"
        notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
        notification.fireDate = NSDate()
        // notification.category = categoryID
        notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)

        NSUserDefaults .standardUserDefaults() .setBool(true, forKey: "isNotificationScheduled")
        NSUserDefaults .standardUserDefaults() .synchronize()
    }
```

**NSUserDefaults class**, you can save settings and properties related to application or user data. For example, you could save a profile image set by the user or a default color scheme for the application. The objects will be saved in what is known as the iOS “defaults system”. The iOS defaults system is available throughout all of the code in your app, and any data saved to the defaults system will persist through application sessions. This means that even if the user closes your application or reboots their phone, the saved data will still be available the next time they open the app

Comment: thanks for your help a will test your code with respect to CalendarUnitHour if it will give me write output i will accept your answer

Comment: I guess CalendarUnitHour will generate notification after each hour.

Comment: Okey.. then it's fine.

Comment: let me know if find any issue in this

Comment: i search google about NSUserDefaults can u explain the working of if(!NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults() .boolForKey("isNotificationScheduled")){
            scheduleNoticaiftion()
        }

Comment: please can u cross check my answer

Comment: If that method won't call in some condition then your notification will never fire(user not register for notification).... But if that work great for you go ahead with that..

Answer (score 2):

Simply add an ID to the userInfo payload when you create the local notification.
Then every time you open the app check if is there a notification with that ID.
If you find it then do nothing, otherwise create a new schedule.
You won't need to store anything in user defaults.

```
-(void) scheduleNotification {
    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

    NSArray *notifications = [app scheduledLocalNotifications];
    for (UILocalNotification* notification in notifications)
    {
        if ([[notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"ID"] isEqualToString:@"MY_NOTIFICATION"])return;
    }

    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    notification.fireDate = [NSDate date];
    notification.alertBody = @"Hey! Upload your latest photos";
    notification.userInfo = @{@"ID":@"MY_NOTIFICATION"};
    notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitDay;
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

    [app scheduleLocalNotification: notification];

}
```

Comment: here is it, you should easily transpose in swift language

Comment: please can you cross check my answer

Answer (score 0):

you have to call `scheduleNoticaiftion()` only one time, so

Try this

```
NSUserDefaults *Check = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([Check boolForKey:@"FirstTime"] == NO) {
    [Check setBool:YES forKey:@"FirstTime"];
    [Check synchronize];
    [self scheduleNoticaiftion];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easy. Use this code

```
notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay
or,
notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitWeekday
```

and All total code wiil be like...

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings) 
{
 if( NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("localNotification") == nil )
 {
 scheduleNoticaiftion()
 }
}

// Schedule the Notifications with repeat
func scheduleNoticaiftion() {
//UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications()

// Schedule the notification********************************************

    let notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.alertBody = "Hey! Upload your latest photos"
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    notification.fireDate = NSDate()
   // notification.category = categoryID
    notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue("registered", forKey: "localNotification")
UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)

}
```